# How to get selected text of currently focused window?

Tags: c#, focus, selection

So, I'm trying to make an application that does the following:

1. Listens for a keyboard shortcut (using [this library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library))
2. When the shortcut is hit, retrieves the contents of the currently selected text, and
3. Processes the text

I've used the method shared by the latest edit of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413266/6605349) ([this method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsapplications/thread/1dc356e6-9441-44de-9eda-247003fa6ef5)) to attach my application to the focused control, but the `GetText` function in that method doesn't do what I need.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21501291/6605349) as well, but that only gives detailed steps as to how to get the focused window on double click, which is not what I need. It did link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13667001/6605349) which led me to try the `WM_KEYDOWN` method (shown below), but that didn't work either.

So far I've tried these `GetText` methods (all within the context of that MSDN post):

```
string GetText(IntPtr handle)
{
    // works in Notepad, but not Chrome
    SendMessageW(handle, WM_COPY, 0, 0);
    string w = Clipboard.GetText();
    return w;

    // works in every app, but in Notepad gets the complete contents
    // and in Chrome gets the window title
    int maxLength = 160;
    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((maxLength + 1) * 2);
    SendMessageW(handle, WM_GETTEXT, maxLength, buffer);
    string w = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(buffer);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
    return w;

    // I would have thought these would work, but
    // they don't do anything for some reason. They
    // all simulate a Ctrl+C.

    SendKeys.SendWait("^c");
    // or
    // this is from the same library that listens for the keyboard shortcut
    KeyboardSimulator.SimulateStandardShortcut(StandardShortcut.Copy);
    // or
    SendMessageW(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, (ushort)Keys.LControlKey, 0);
    SendMessageW(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, (ushort)Keys.C, 0);
    SendMessageW(handle, WM_KEYUP, (ushort)Keys.C, 0);
    SendMessageW(handle, WM_KEYUP, (ushort)Keys.LControlKey, 0);
    // after any of those
    string w = Clipboard.GetText();
    return w;
}
```

(I don't care about preserving the clipboard yet.)

How can I consistently get the selected text of the currently focused application? Bonus points for not tampering with the clipboard, but using it is OK too.

Comment: Look into Microsoft UI Automation

Comment: @MickyD it would help if you posted an answer showing how to use it for this purpose.

Comment: The *WM_COPY* and *WM_GETTEXT* they dont work always as stated at MSDN docs for these messages. So the problem is simulating or listening to *ctrl+c*?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε if WM_COPY and WM_GETTEXT don't always work as stated, then I guess problem is simulating Ctrl+C (not listening to)

Comment: @MickyD could you please explain how MS UI Automation could be used for this purpose?

Comment: Certainly, see below. Sorry for delay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ever since Vista, apps should refrain from using p-invoke or `WM_GETTEXT` to snoop on other apps due to potential blocks from Windows Elevated Processes.  Instead consider using *Microsoft UI Automation*.  Though arguably a testing framework, it is also useful as a means to remotely interact with another GUI application.

MSDN:

> Microsoft UI Automation is the new accessibility framework for Microsoft Windows. It addresses the needs of assistive technology products and automated test frameworks by providing programmatic access to information about the user interface (UI). In addition, UI Automation enables control and application developers to make their products accessible.

The following code will look for the running process *Notepad* and grab any text selection.  **Ensure you run notepad beforehand**, enter in some text and select a word or two.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Automation;

namespace UiaTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();       
            var root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);

            var documentControl = new                                 
                    PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, 
                                      ControlType.Document);

            var textPatternAvailable = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsTextPatternAvailableProperty, true);

            var findControl = new AndCondition(documentControl, textPatternAvailable);

            var targetDocument = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, findControl);    
            var textPattern = targetDocument.GetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern) as TextPattern;

            foreach (var selection in textPattern.GetSelection())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Selection: \"{selection.GetText(255)}\"");
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

> How can I consistently get the selected text of the currently **focused** application?

Now in your case to work from focused window, instead of:

```
var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
```

...perform a:

```
IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
var root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(handle);
```

...where `GetForegroundWindow` is defined as:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

### See also

- *[UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/index)*
- *[Obtain Text Attributes Using UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/obtain-text-attributes-using-ui-automation)*
- *[Find and Highlight Text Using UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/find-and-highlight-text-using-ui-automation)*
- *[Invoke a Control Using UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/invoke-a-control-using-ui-automation)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you show me how to get the selected text of the currently focused window (the actual question), rather than a particular window by name? That would help out a lot.

Comment: Hm, this method works for Notepad but when I try to use the selected text in Chrome (even a textarea) the `targetDocument` turns out to be `null` and I get a NullReferenceException where it says `targetDocument.GetCurrentPattern`. What am I missing?

Comment: @KenHilton that’s a new question.   You need to enumerate the elements to find the appropriate control.   This answer gives you more than enough to start

Comment: I see. I'll accept this answer in that case, thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

We can also simulate copy shortcut (press Ctrl + C)
And after that read clipboard

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).